# using alamofire object mapper causing error for converting my class to Any

Tags: swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I'm using Alamofire and AlamofireObjectMapper in my code .

This is my class that im trying to map :

```
    import ObjectMapper

import ObjectMapper

class ApplicationCollection: Mappable {

    var title:String?
    var name:String?
    var collectionDescription:String?
    var collectionId:Int!
    var applications:[Application]?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        title <- map["title"]
        collectionDescription <- map["description"]
        collectionId <- map["id"]
        applications <- map["applications"]

    }
}
```

And I'm trying to use this class in my API struct like this :

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import AlamofireObjectMapper

struct API {

    static let URL = "http://mysite.dev/"
    enum Path {
        case application(Int)
        case mainPageCollections
        var url:String {
            let path:String

            switch self {
            case .application(let appId):
                path = "applicatipn/\(appId)"
            case .mainPageCollections:
                path = "ApplicationCollections"
            }

            return API.URL + path

        }

    }

    static func getRuleSetDetail(callback: @escaping (DataResponse<ApplicationCollection>) -> Void){
        _ = Alamofire.request(Path.mainPageCollections.url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON(completionHandler: callback)
    }

}
```

and then I get this error :

Cannot convert value of type '(DataResponse) -> Void' to expected argument type '(DataResponse) -> Void'

How I can fix This compile error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
_ = Alamofire.request(Path.mainPageCollections.url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseObject(completionHandler: callback)
```

then you can confrim to base mappable protocol